# django zip unequal lists

Tags: python, django, list, zip

I have 2 queries that you can find print results as below.

```
<QuerySet [{'swtype': 1}, {'swtype': 2}]>
 <QuerySet ['201;203;205', '207;208']>
```

I looked some commands at stackoverflow for pairing these lists as per below.

```
pair = itertools.zip_longest(swtype, p_list)
```

But the output is not as I was seeking. It's like

```
1:201
2:203
none:205
none:207
none:208
```

What I am after is to have:

```
1:201
none:203
none:205
2:207
none:208
```

Is that possible by zipping or should I create 2 seperate loops.
If I create 2 seperate loops than I am having other problems.

Comment: Do you pair these immediately? I have the idea that you do some processing with the second queryset in order to generate a `p_list`...

Comment: Not immediately,  I get those from .objects.filter results,then process lists than zipping :) What's on your mind ?

Comment: But the elements of `p_list` are `201`, `203`, etc. Whereas in the queryset, it appears like a single string `'201;203;205'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do some processing of the second queryset, to split it by the semicolon (`;`) into substrings. The problem with that is that then the structure is lost, and thus you `zip` as if these were always independent elements. You can however keep the structure, and work with:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

qs1 = [{'swtype': 1}, {'swtype': 2}]  # first queryset
qs2 = ['201;203;205', '207;208']      # second queryset

result = chain.from_iterable(
    zip_longest((qi1['swtype'],), qi2.split(';')) for qi1, qi2 in zip(qs1, qs2)
)
```

We here thus iterate over the two *querysets* `qi1` and `qi2`, and we then perform a `zip_longest` on `qi1[swtype]` (wrapped into a *singleton tuple* since we need an iterable, and we split the string of `qi2` into substrings with `qi2.split(';')`). We then `chain` the "*subzips*" together.

Note however that if the two querysets originate from a similar query, I would advice you to merge the two queries into one. This is safer since it the order is guaranteed to match, and furthermore usually (there are some exceptions), it is more efficient as well.

Comment: you can add to your answer example with `qs1 = [{'swtype': 1}, {'swtype': 2}]` and `qs2 = ['201;203;205', '207;208']`

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I can't actually do single query because I am getting query result of the second one based on the first query input.